# Rust does not recognize a slice

Tags: rust

I have a `[u8; 128]` that I would like to print. To do so, I am passing in a borrow of that buffer to `println!` using debug formatting. However, I am receiving a compiler error.

The compiler says that `[u8;128]` does not implement `std::fmt::Debug`. However, I am passing in a borrow to `println!`, which leads me to question why Rust does not recognize this is a slice. I was able to fix the problem by attaching `[#derive(Debug)]` to a struct with one member, `buf: &[u8]`. Passing my buffer in through this struct to `println!` solves the problem, which tells me that `&[u8]` does indeed implement `std::fmt::Debug`.

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpStream;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Fah<'a> {
    buf: &'a[u8],
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("216.58.194.206:80")?;

    stream.write(&[1])?;
    let mut buf = [0; 128];
    stream.read(&mut buf)?;
    println!("buf: {:?}", &buf); // This line does not compile
    println!("fah: {:?}", Fah { buf: &buf}); // This line works fine
    Ok(())
}
```

Playground link: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b95ad4762f23ca35e890d0cbd2c072ce

I expect this to compile just fine. However, the compiler complains that `the trait std::fmt::Debug is not implemented for [u8; 128]`, as I said before.

Comment: Note that this code could compile in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&buf` is a `&[u8; 128]` that gets implicitly coerced (by [unsizing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html)) to `&[u8]` a lot of the time. If you’re explicit about wanting the slice, [it’ll work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5aaf81522bf8edb5590d37a1194aec5f):

```
println!("{:?}", &a as &[u8]);
```

but also just ask for a slice in the first place:

```
println!("{:?}", &a[..]);
```